# select a random rows from table

Tags: mysql, select, random

I have two tables one called topic as shown below!

topic_id   topic_name
1             topic 1 
2             topic 2 
3             topic 3

and another table called questions as shown

q_id   question_name   topic_id
1        question 1           1 
2        question 2           1 
3        question 3           1 
4        question 4           2 
5        question 5           2 
6        question 6           2 
7        question 7           3 
8        question 8           3 
9        question 9           3

i want to choose random 2 question from given three topic. Someone please help me to fix this issue

Comment: so the questions should necesarily belong to different topics or not?

Comment: @NikosM. the result should contain 2 question each from every topic and question need to be selected randomely--- thanks for replay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get list of topics with their question IDs `GROUP_CONCAT([column] order by RAND())`.
And then link table to itself.

```
SELECT t.q_id, t.question_name, t.topic_id
FROM table t
JOIN (
    SELECT topic_id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(q_id ORDER BY RAND()), ',', 2) as qList
    FROM table GROUP BY topic_id
) tGrouped ON FIND_IN_SET(t.q_id, tGrouped.qList)>0
```

Comment: @user2399505 note that this can be even slower (for large tables) since it includes both random sorting and joining tables

Answer (score 2):

One can [sort the rows randomly and then fetch the top row from this random order](http://davidwalsh.name/mysql-random)

For two random questions which **could have same topic**:

```
SELECT * FROM questions 
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 2
```

For two random questions which should have **different topic**:
Use 2 different queries which take as parameters two different topic_ids (t1, t2):

First select 2 random topic ids (similarly to above code):

```
SELECT topic_id FROM topics 
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 2
```

Then select 2 random questions with these topics ids (2 select statements)

```
SELECT * FROM questions 
WHERE topic_id = t1
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 1

SELECT * FROM questions 
WHERE topic_id = t2
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 1
```

UPDATE (after OP's comment and explanation)

To obtain two random questions from every topic use a variation of the above solutions:

3 select statements (one for each topic):

```
SELECT * FROM questions 
WHERE topic_id = needed_topic_id_here
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 2
```

repeat the select for every topic_id.

Presumably these select statements could be combined into one big select statement, but i'm not sure at this point.

**Note** as pointed out in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28992371/3591273), this could be less efficient (to randomly select in pure sql) and a better solution would be to pre-compute random indices in PHP (or whatever your platform is) and **then** actually select the random questions. Since no language is mentioned in the question, i'll leave it here (and point to the other answer(s) for this approach)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ORDER BY RAND()` and `LIMIT 2` in the query but it runs painfully slow for tables that have thousand of records or more.

A better approach for big tables is to get the bounding values of the `PK` field using the `WHERE` condition you need, generate 2 random numbers smaller between these bounding values in PHP then issue 2 MySQL queries to get 2 questions.

Something along these lines:

```
$query = '
    SELECT MIN(q_id) AS min_id, MAX(q_id) AS max_id
    FROM questions
    WHERE topic_id = 1        # put the filtering you need here
';
// Run the query
// ... use your regular PHP code for database access here ...
// get and store the returned values in PHP variables $minId and $maxId


// Keep the generated random values here to avoid duplicates
$list = array();

// Get N random questions from the database
for ($cnt = 0; $cnt < N; $cnt ++) {
    // Generate a new ID that is not in the list
    do {
        $id = rand($minId, $maxId);
    } while (in_array($id, $list);

    // Put it into the list to avoid generating it again
    $list[] = $id;

    // Get the random question
    $query = "
        SELECT *
        FROM questions
        WHERE topic_id = 1
          AND q_id <= $id
        ORDER BY q_id DESC
        LIMIT 1
    ";
    // Run the query, get the question
    // ... use your regular PHP code for database access here ...
}
```

No matter what queries you run (these or others provided by other answer), you need indexes on `q_id` and the columns used in the `WHERE` clause.

I hope `q_id` is the `PK` of the table which means it already is an `UNIQUE INDEX`.

Answer (score 0):

Provide 3 topic ids to get 2 questions at random:

`select
 q.question_name
from
 topics t,
 questions q
where
 t.topic_id = q.topic_id and
 t.topic_id in (1, 2, 3) /*define your 3 given topics*/
order by rand() limit 0,2;`

Comment: Why should the OP try this? Please add an explanation of what you did and why you did it that way not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.